# mvc4 how to convert image to base64 in the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

i have this view

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.passportImage, new { placeholder = "Uploadt Your Passport", type = "file"})
```

and in the model i have this field:

```
public byte[] passportImage { get; set; }
```

my question is how **in the view** i can convert the image to base64, because the controller make exception if i didn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
var base64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(passportImage , 0, passportImage .Length);
```

You could potentially make this a derived field on your model:

```
public string Base64Image
{
  get
  {
    return System.Convert.ToBase64String(passportImage , 0, passportImage .Length);
  }
}
```

Comment: is that code in view? please describe more i am new to mvc4 with image

Comment: please Mr. TGH, would give me a working code, i really new to MVC with image and I tired of googling, please help me